# ScrollView overlaps between two views above it, making the content show between the two views. How to fix?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm trying to make a tab system.. It looks like this:
[image]

But when I scroll up, the scrollview contents overflow between the tab and header.

[image]

Here is my code:

**The view you're seeing**

```swift
struct ItineraryDetailView: View {
    let itinerary: ItineraryDisplay
    @State var currentTab: Int = 0
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("\(itinerary.numberOfDays) Days in \(itinerary.city)")
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .frame(alignment: .center)
            
            ZStack(alignment: .top) {
                TabView(selection: self.$currentTab) {
                    ScrollView {
                        Spacer()
                            .frame(height: 60)
                        // Details
                        ForEach(Array(itinerary.activities.enumerated()), id: \.offset) { index, element in
                            Text("Day \(index + 1)")
                                .font(.title)
                            
                            ForEach(element, id: \.self) { activity in
                                VStack {
                                    Text("\u{2022} \(activity)")
                                        .padding(5)
                                }
                                .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading) // Achieves the Text() alignment we want
                            }
                            
                            Divider()
                        }
                        .padding(5)
                    }
                    .tag(0)
                    
                    // Highlights
                    Text("hi")
                        .tag(1)
                }
                .tabViewStyle(.page(indexDisplayMode: .never))
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                
                TopTabBarView(currentTab: self.$currentTab)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**The custom tab implementation:**

```swift
struct TopTabBarView: View {
    @Binding var currentTab: Int
    @Namespace var namespace

    var tabBarOptions: [String] = ["Plan", "Details"]
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
            HStack(spacing: 20) {
                ForEach(Array(zip(self.tabBarOptions.indices, self.tabBarOptions)), id: \.0) { index, name in
                    TopTabBarItem(currentTab: self.$currentTab, namespace: namespace.self, tabBarItemName: name, tab: index)
                }
            }
            .padding(.horizontal)
        }
        .background(Color.white)
        .frame(height: 80)
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        .padding(10)
    }
}

struct TopTabBarItem: View {
    @Binding var currentTab: Int
    let namespace: Namespace.ID

    var tabBarItemName: String
    var tab: Int
    
    var body: some View {
        Button {
            self.currentTab = tab
        } label: {
            VStack {
                Text(tabBarItemName)
                if currentTab == tab {
                    Color.black
                        .frame(height: 2)
                        .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "underline", in: namespace, properties: .frame)
                } else {
                    Color.clear.frame(height: 2)
                }
            }
            .animation(.spring(), value: self.currentTab)
        }
        .buttonStyle(.plain)
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? I have pulled half my hair out trying to solve this, the right side of my head is almost bald at this point. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Apply the `frame` first, then color in the `background`.

```
struct TopTabBarView: View {
    ...
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
            ...
        }
        // notice the change in order here:
        .frame(height: 80)
        .background(Color.white)
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        // the horizontal padding added here also reveals the scroll view on the sides
        // .padding(10)
    }
}
```

The scroll view doesn't actually need that much height. So if you color in the scroll view's background, then allow it to lay out in a much higher frame, it centers itself vertically in that frame, leaving out some "transparent" space.

Also consider using `.frame(height: 80, alignment: .bottom)` to position the bar at the bottom of the 80-high frame.